# PHP generated link in echo

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I am trying to get this php link inside of a php function to work, but I'm not sure how. Here is what I have:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo 'You are logged in.';
} else {
echo 'To post a new job posting, 
<a href="http://www.example.de/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a> or 
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>.';
}
?>
```

The reason I have the php link is because I want to the user to be redirected to the current page after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
 <?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'You are logged in.';
    } else {
    echo 'To post a new job posting, 
    <a href="http://www.example.de/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a> or 
    <a href="'.wp_login_url( get_permalink()).'" title="Login">Login</a>.';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You've missed a bracket there, near get_permalink()

Answer (score 0):

You have embedded a php script inside a string in a php script. Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo 'You are logged in.';
} else {
echo 'To post a new job posting, 
<a href="http://www.example.de/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a> or 
<a href="'.wp_login_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Login">Login</a>.';
}
?>
```